# Transform multipart/form-data request body then use validationPipe

Tags: typescript, transform, nestjs, class-validator

I'm trying to convert a formData requert from string to json object with transform and after that validate with the validationPipe (class-validator) but I get

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at cloneObject (E:\projectos\Gitlab\latineo\latineo-apirest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:290:21)
    at clone (E:\projectos\Gitlab\latineo\latineo-apirest\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:204:16)
```

After try to debug I enter into my controller 3 times and the object is saved in the database but with no validation and inner transformJSONToObject 9 times ...

My main.ts

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }));
  app.use(helmet());
  app.enableCors();
  app.use(
    rateLimit({
      windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
      max: 4000, // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
    }),
  );
  app.use(compression());
  app.use('/upload', express.static(join(__dirname, '..', 'upload')));
  const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('XXX')
    .setDescription('XXX')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addBearerAuth()
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

My nestjs dto

```
export class CreateRestaurantDto {
  // to do, check the documentation from class-validator for array of objects
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ApiModelProperty({ type: String })
  @Length(3, 100)
  readonly name: string;
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ApiModelProperty({ type: String })
  @Length(3, 500)
  readonly description: string;
  @Transform(transformJSONToObject, { toClassOnly: true })
  @ValidateNested()
  @ApiModelProperty({ type: [RestaurantsMenu] })
  readonly menu: RestaurantsMenu[];
  @Transform(transformJSONToObject, { toClassOnly: true })
  @IsString({
    each: true,
  })
  @IsNotEmpty({
    each: true,
  })
  @Length(3, 50, { each: true })
  @ApiModelProperty({ type: [String] })
  readonly type: string[];
  @Transform(transformJSONToObject, { toClassOnly: true })
  @ValidateNested()
  @ApiModelProperty({ type: [RestaurantsLocation] })
  readonly location: RestaurantsLocation[];
}
```

Here is my Controller

```
 @ApiBearerAuth()
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('imageUrls'))
  @ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
  @ApiImplicitFile({
    name: 'imageUrls',
    required: true,
    description: 'List of restaurants',
  })
  @Post()
  async createRestaurant(
    @Body() createRestaurantDto: CreateRestaurantDto,
    @UploadedFiles() imageUrls,
    @Req() request: any,
  ): Promise<RestaurantDocument> {
    const userId = request.payload.userId;
    const user = await this.usersService.findUserById(userId);
    const mapUrls = imageUrls.map(element => {
      return element.path;
    });
    const restaurant = {
      ...createRestaurantDto,
      imagesUrls: mapUrls,
      creator: user,
    };
 // just add a resturant to mongodb
    const createdRestaurant = await this.restaurantsService.addRestaurant(
      restaurant,
    );
    user.restaurants.push(createdRestaurant);
    user.save();
    return createdRestaurant;
  }
```

Comment: `const createdRestaurant = await this.restaurantsService.createRestaurant(
      ... );` You're using recursion without a condition. You keep calling `createRestaurant` over and over without an exit condition.

Comment: Why I need a condition there with no transform it just pass one time

Comment: @Train the `createRestaurant` being called is the one from the `RestaurantService` class. Though I do admit that having the same method name in controller and service can be a bit confusing.

Comment: ye that is it I will edit for avoid that.

Answer (score 10):

I know it is too late now :) but maybe this can help someone

with the help of deep-parse-json, my solution is to create a `ParseFormDataJsonPipe` as below and put it right before `ValidationPipe`.
you can pass an excepted list of form-data's properties in the constructor to keep some things purely such as image, binary, jsonArray...

```js
import { PipeTransform, ArgumentMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';
import { deepParseJson } from 'deep-parse-json';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

type TParseFormDataJsonOptions = {
  except?: string[];
};

export class ParseFormDataJsonPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private options?: TParseFormDataJsonOptions) {}

  transform(value: any, _metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    const { except } = this.options;
    const serializedValue = value;
    const originProperties = {};
    if (except?.length) {
      _.merge(originProperties, _.pick(serializedValue, ...except));
    }
    const deserializedValue = deepParseJson(value);
    console.log(`deserializedValue`, deserializedValue);
    return { ...deserializedValue, ...originProperties };
  }
}
```

here is an example of the controller

```js
  @Post()
  @ApiBearerAuth('admin')
  @ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, RoleGuard)
  @Roles(Role.Admin)
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('image', {
      limits: { fileSize: imgurConfig.fileSizeLimit },
    }),
  )
  async createProductByAdmin(
    @Body(
      new ParseFormDataJsonPipe({ except: ['image', 'categoryIds'] }),
      new ValidationPipe(),
    )
    createDto: CreateProductDto,
    @UploadedFile() image: Express.Multer.File,
  ) {
    console.log(`createDto`, createDto);
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) library for your`s DTO

```
import { Transform, Type } from 'class-transformer';
```

1. For objects:

```
  @Transform(({ value }) => JSON.parse(value))
  name: { small:string, middle:string, big:string };
```

2. For numbers:

```
  @Type(() => Number)
  count number;
```

Comment: This answer is perfect, in my case my form was working perfectly until i had to use multipart form in order to add a file to the payload. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with this for some time. Recently I found a solution that seems simple and decent to me. So I will post it even though this post is a bit old, in case it can help someone.

You can create an interceptor to extract the field in the multipart formdata that contains the json, and then parse it and assign it to the request body. Suppose you call this field `body`. Then the interceptor would look like this

```js
@Injectable()
export class BodyInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest<Request>();

    try {
      const body = JSON.parse(request.body.body);
      request.body = body;
    } catch (err) {
      throw new BadRequestException(err.message);
    }

    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

I envelop the `JSON.parse()` code in a try/catch so that, if you pass invalid JSON (wrong syntax), you will get an error that will be (mostly) the same as Nest's default one for this specific case.

Then, you can simply call this interceptor after `FileInterceptor`

```js
@UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files'), BodyInterceptor)
```

And then you can type your body according to your DTO using `@Body()` and hopefully it will work. I tested it a bit and it seems to be working properly, please let me know otherwise. Hope it helps, best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

just in case this could help someone, i had a similar issue with a more complicated case where i was sending a form with a file AND and other types of data like dates and numbers inside it.

2 ways to handle validation properly:

- 1 make sure to explicitly cast to string BEFORE setting value in formData.

  ```
  for (let i in value) {
    formData.append(i, value[i] === null ? "" : value[i]);
  }
  ```
- 2 Use this transformation function:

  ```
  const transformDateFn = (params: TransformFnParams) =>
    params.obj[params.key] === "" || params.obj[params.key] === "null"
      ? null
      : params.value;
  ```

alongside with:

```
    @Transform(transformDateFn)
    @IsOptional()
    @Type(() => Date)
    @IsDate()
    myFieldName: Date;
```

I know it looks like madness, but actualy if you don't apply the explicit cast in solution 1, formData will transform null to a string equal to "null", resulting in a nasty validation problem that will cause you some heavy headaches.

If we break it now:

1- @Transform will transform the value

2- @IsOptional() will ignore validation on null properties (make sure to apply ignore the option is pipes before!)

```
 app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      enableDebugMessages: true,
      skipNullProperties: true,
      transform: true,
      validationError: {
        value: true,
        target: true,
      },
   }),
 );
```

3- @Type will force casting to the right type if value is not null.

4- @IsDate Now validation can run.

This is it. Feel free to comment if you have further questions.